# How to stop Netbeans opening my index on run?

Tags: html, css, netbeans, indexing

When I run my project in Netbeans 6.8, it loves to open the index page automatically. It's annoying because I always keep a tab with the page I'm working on when I work, so I don't need this index page. It also makes my current page lose focus.

I have tried not specifying an index or my project URL, but then I can't run or save my project.

How can I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 2):

In NetBeans 7.4:

- Right-click your project, select 'Properties'
- In left hand pane of popup, select 'Run Configuration'
- In the right pane of the popup, in the bottom right corner of the list of fields, click 'Advanced...'
- Select radio button 'Do Not Open Web Browser'

Answer (score 2):

I ran into that issue as well. The solution is quite simple - go to the menu bar:

Run/Run File.

That's it. It will just run the current php script without going to the index.php.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to reopen the same page (refresh it ?) in the browser ? You can set settings in the project properties > run configuration, then chaange the index file or project url. But apart from that I am afraid that you can't do anything to prevent opening a new window on run. When you click 'run', netbeans says to your OS : "Hey, let's open that page (your_project_URL/index_file) now". The OS thinks and execute a command like "default_browser url", where the argument "url" is here your_project_URL/index_file. Then the browser thinks it's a new page to open, and BAM, opens a new page.

Comment: I always have the page I am working on (never index.php unless I'm working on it) so every single I run the project (once every minute I guess) I have to close the new tab...

Comment: Instead of running the project, save all the pages (ctyrl+shift+S), and refresh your page ?! It's basically what you want, don't you?

Comment: When I run the project, it uploads all files to my webserver. When I save the project, it saves all files to my local disk. That's how I've set it up. I don't want to upload files when I save all, since I save every minute or so.

Comment: Right click on your project : project proertied > Run configuration > Advanced > Do not open web browser   Does it upload your file, save everything, without opening your browser ?

Comment: @Cedric is there any idea how we can do that in netbeans 8? I follow your solution but I cant find what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Just use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> which will open the current page with focus.